# Adjusting time 4 hours behind in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which displays the time in which the database was created in, which is actually 4 hours ahead.  In my output, I want the time to be taken back 4 hours to show ,the correct time.  The date column was created as a numeric value (17,9) not null. 
E.g. 20130627.180846113

---

I then converted it into two separate columns displaying
E.g. Date: 2013-06-28
E.g. Time: 17:11:43

However I'm not sure where to account for the -4 hours in my query.  Can anyone make a suggestion as to what the query might look like with the correct time display?  Please note I'm using SQL server management studio 2008.

### Existing Query:

```
  WITH CTE AS
  (
  SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                         SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                         SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                         SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                         RIGHT([Date],3)) [Date],
        ItemId,
        MsgID,
        Parms,
        [OBJECT]
 FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,MsgID,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
                Parms,
                [OBJECT]
        FROM JnlList
        WHERE UserCode = 'Automation') A
 )
 SELECT  ItemId, MsgID,
    CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) [Date],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Date],108) AS [Time],
    CASE WHEN MsgID = '1' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) +' Was removed from:'
    WHEN MsgID = '2' THEN 'This Move List has been cleared of all its media'
    ELSE '' -- Optional Else
    END AS [RemovalPath],
    [OBJECT] [Move List:]
 FROM CTE
 WHERE [Date] >= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Is it really always 4 hours, or is it the wrong time zone? In that case, differences in daylight savings changes may make you unhappy later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DATEADD() to adjust TIME:

```
DATEADD(hour,-4,timefield)
```

In your query (assuming rest of query is fine):

```
 SELECT  ItemId, MsgID,
    CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) [Date],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(hour,-4,CAST([Date] AS TIME)),108) AS [Time],
    CASE WHEN MsgID = '1' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) +' Was removed from:'
    WHEN MsgID = '2' THEN 'This Move List has been cleared of all its media'
    ELSE '' -- Optional Else
    END AS [RemovalPath],
    [OBJECT] [Move List:]
 FROM CTE
 WHERE [Date] >= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: where specifically would I add that in the query?

Comment: wny not just do date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 4 HOUR); instead of that complex mess you have

Comment: @GoatCo this changed my time column output from 5:11:43 TO 1900-01-01 13:11:43.000

Comment: @GoatCo This has changed the time appropriately but it is giving me microseconds again.  Is there anyway to show the proper time and remove the microseconds?

Comment: @GoatCo The time output is: 13:11:43.50700000

Comment: Just wrap it in the CONVERT() you had used previously, see update above.

Comment: @GoatCo Thanks, I was trying that but I missed a closing bracket.  I appreciate your help.